# Quando usar Darmos/ dar-mos/ darmo-nos/ damos /dá-mos?

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes, conjugações

Quando devemos utilizar cada um deles? Há muita gente com dificuldade em distinguir quando usar o quê, principalmente quando por hífen ou não.

Já agora, «dar-mo-nos» é correto?

Comment: Acho que esta pergunta podia ser formulada de forma mais genérica, pois o problema da colocação correta do hífen acontece frequentemente com muitos outros verbos. O caso de "dar" é interessante por ser um verbo transitivo direto e indireto, ou seja, liga-se tanto a um objeto direto (o que é dado) como a um indireto (a quem é dado), pelo que "-mos" é válido (ao contrário de, por exemplo, "falar-mos"), mas não é de todo um caso único.

Comment: Se tiveres alguma ideia de como poderá ficar mais genérica e que não mude o sentido da pergunta eu altero.

Comment: Infelizmente, não tenho conhecimento da língua além da curiosidade como utilizador, pelo que as generalizações que eu poderia fazer dependem de exemplos que por acaso conheça (e com sorte me lembre), e não de estruturas que um estudioso da língua possa identificar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos ver as [conjugações do verbo "dar"](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-dar).

## Damos

A forma "*damos*" corresponde a forma plural da primeira pessoa do modo presente do indicativo do verbo "dar", que se conjuga "nós damos".

Exemplo:

> **Nós damos** ao aniversariante um belo bolo de chocolate.

## Darmos

A forma "*darmos*" corresponde a forma plural da primeira pessoa do infinitivo impessoal do verbo "dar", que se "para darmos nós".

Exemplo:

> Não se esqueçam que foi combinado que é **para darmos nós** o bolo, e não os refrigerantes.

## Dar-mos

A forma "*dar-mos*" corresponde a contração de "*dar-me os*", aonde "*me*" é um [pronome pessoal do caso oblíquo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_obl%C3%ADquo) que significa "para mim" (sendo "mim" um outro pronome do caso oblíquo). É transformado nesta forma por causa da [contração com os pronomes oblíquos átonos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_obl%C3%ADquo#Contra%C3%A7%C3%B5es_dos_obl%C3%ADquos_%C3%A1tonos), onde "*me + os = mos*".

Entretanto, esta forma [é incomum de ser utilizada](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica077.html).

Um exemplo:

> — Aqui estão os livros.
>   — Você poderia **dar-mos**?

## Dá-mos

A forma "*dá-mos*" funciona de forma semelhante a "*dar-mos*", sendo equaivalente a "*dá-me os*". A forma "*dá*" do verbo "*dar*" ocorre em duas situações:

- Terceira pessoa no singular do modo indicativo, que se conjuga "*ele dá*" ou "*ela dá*".
- Segunda pessoa no singular do modo imperativo afirmativo, que se conjuga "*dá tu*".

Desta forma, podemos construir ou exemplo parecido com o anterior:

> — Aqui estão os livros. Você quer que eu te dê eles?
>   — Sim, eu quero. **Dá-mos**.

## Dar-mo-nos

Esta forma usa uma [mesóclise](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal). Veja como isso seria se convertêssemos para próclise ou ênclise:

- Mo darnos.
- Darnos mo.

Nenhuma das duas formas está correta, pois "*mo*" não é um pronome oblíquo e "*darnos*" não é uma conjugação existente do verbo "*dar*". **Logo, "*dar-mo-nos*" não existe.**

## Darmo-nos *

A forma "*darmo-nos*" é a combinação de "*darmos*" (embora sem o *s*), tal como explicado acima, com o pronome oblíquo "nos".

Exemplo:

> — Querida, poderíamos **darmo-nos** uma segunda lua de mel como presente de aniversário de casamento.

* <sup><sub>Sugerido pelo bfavaretto em um comentário.</sub></sup>

## Referências

- http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-dar
- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_oblíquo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_obl%C3%ADquo)
- http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica077.html
- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocação_pronominal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal)
- http://www.jn.pt/Dossies/dossie.aspx?content_id=4147681&dossier=Portugu%EAs%20atual