# Em redações oficiais, devemos usar "Vimos" ou "Venho"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, formalismo

Quando vamos escrever um ofício ou um memorando, após o cabeçalho, destinatário e vocativo, com qual é mais comum iniciar o texto?

Com:

> Vimos por meio deste (...).

ou com:

> Venho por meio deste (...).

Devemos usar *Vimos* ou *Venho*?
Qual é a forma correta?

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Mas vale notar que, ao menos no Brasil, essa expressão é cada vez menos utilizada, mesmo em documentos formais. Simplesmente porque ela é desnecessária (você não vem literalmente pela carta/memorando, e é muito óbvio que você usa a carta/memorando para comunicar o que quer que esteja comunicando). Assim, muitos [profissionais](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/55ik4) e [estudiosos de comunicação](http://www.manuelarodriguez.com.br/apresenta_artigo.aspx?id=47&campo=artigos), recomendam não usar esse tipo de expressão para iniciar uma comunicação.

Comment: Então começamos como @LuizVieira?

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que vai depender bastante do contexto, mas pode ser direto ao ponto: "Solicito...", "Informo...". Ou também uma introdução para  dar contexto, tipo "O PL é um site de Q&A... Recomendo sua inclusão na lista de..."

Comment: @JorgeB. Exatamente como o colega Molx falou. Ao invés de usar "Vimos por meio desta informar que...", prefere-se utilizar "Informamos que...".

Comment: Na minha humilde opnião. A forma singular se refere a você. Quando você está representando uma empresa, instituição ou coletividade você deveria usar o plural.

Comment: Acredito que ser mais claro e limpo seja o ideal.
Por quê colocar: -Venho através deste solicitar... se posso utilizar: Solicito...
Ou estou equivocado?
em minha opinião este é o melhor modo de redigir um documento oficial, sendo claro e preciso!
Ex. Solicito... Ao invés de: Venho por meio deste solicitar... Informo... Ao invés de: Venho por meio deste informar... Agradeço... Ao invés de: Venho por meio deste agradecer...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As duas formas são corretas, depende é de quem está "a escrever" (remetente) o ofício ou  memorando. Se for por exemplo uma empresa usamos o "Vimos por meio deste..." porquê se refere a empresa (Nós):

> Vimos (Nós empresa) por meio deste...

No caso de ser eu a escrever em meu próprio nome usa-se "Venho por meio deste":

> Venho (eu) por meio deste...

Comment: Escrever "usa-mos" é um erro crasso.

Comment: @E_net4 tem toda a razão. Por isso eu fiz esta pergunta [Quando usar Darmos/ dar-mos/ darmo-nos/ damos /dá-mos?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/301/153)

Comment: Embora seja correto, o uso de "vir por meio deste" está caindo em desuso por ser desnecessariamente formal e servir somente para "inchar" a carta. Atualmente (pelo menos no Brasil) se usa muito mais informar / comunicar / solicitar ("Informamos que..." / "Comunico que...", etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Essa decisão depende do número gramatical do emissor. Normalmente existe numa identificação dos intervenientes no fim do documento, com uma assinatura. Se este foi redigido por mais do que uma pessoa, as frases deverão tomar a pessoa "nós", no plural. Se uma pessoa está a publicar em nome de várias pessoas, também poderá usar o plural, desde que se dê a entender que as restantes concordam com a mensagem. Nos restantes casos, mesmo havendo uma pessoa que fala por uma entidade coletiva, o singular é o mais adequado. O exemplo a seguir é de uma simples carta, mas um ofício ou memorando pode seguir o mesmo molde (exibe entidades fictícias):

> Venho por este meio informar que a sua pergunta a Álvaro Campos foi remetida. Deverá aguardar entre dois a três dias úteis pela sua resposta.
>
> Os melhores cumprimentos,
>
> O Secretário da Comissão de heterónimos Fernando Pessoa,
>
> Ricardo Reis

A mesma lógica é imposta independentemente dos verbos utilizados no texto. O redator poderá optar ainda por reduzir o número de ocorrências de indicação do sujeito através da forma passiva, o que é feito frequentemente em artigos científicos e outros documentos formais.

Answer (score -1):

As duas formas estão corretas, depende do remetente, a grande confusão é por serem formas conjugadas dos verbos (ver e vir), mas conjugadas em tempos verbais diferentes.

Comment: Bruno, bem-vindo à comunidade. Achas mesmo que alguém vai pensar que *vimos* em *vimos por meio deste ofício solicitar [qualquer coisa]*  é conjugação do verbo *ver?*

Answer (score -3):

Exemplo:

> Boa tarde! D. Luísa,
>
> Venho através deste email solicitar o agendamento para quinta-feira, dia 23/05/2019 ás 14:00 horas, para sra. Geane Santos, sindica, validar o certificado digital do Condomínio Mares de Piata.
>
> Informo que a Sra. Geane, nos lê em copia.
>
> Atenciosamente,

Comment: E porquê "venho" e não "vimos"?

Comment: Para a resposta ficar minimamente sólida, convinha explicar. No mínimo, explicar o porquê de usar uma forma e não a outra.